# Website Responsive Issues

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have just launched my website http://www.connorgraham.com.au and am having responsive issues, specifically with mobile. Prior to launch, everything was working and looking perfect, however I have just realised that on mobile 20% of the right side of the screen is just white. The website should be full width and there shouldn't be this blank space showing.

I would appreciate any help, and am happy to provide any of my code if it would help solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have explained the responsive grid system Via bootstrap you can check
https://attariwebsol.wordpress.com/2015/04/24/bootstrap-grid-system/
and tell if this is not helpful to you I will explained according to your layout.

Answer (score 0):

In your `'<head>'`

change `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`  to  `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` this should fix your issue.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this seemed to work at first, but then I realised that you can now scroll the page left and right on mobile. Is there a way to fix this?